# pandas sum the differences between two columns in each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `df` looks like,

```
A               B              C    D
2017-10-01      2017-10-11     M    2017-10
2017-10-02      2017-10-03     M    2017-10
2017-11-01      2017-11-04     B    2017-11
2017-11-08      2017-11-09     B    2017-11
2018-01-01      2018-01-03     A    2018-01
```

the `dtype` of `A` and `B` are `datetime64`, `C` and `D` are of `strings`;

I like to `groupby` `C` and `D` and get the differences between `B` and `A`,

```
df.groupby(['C', 'D']).apply(lambda row: row['B'] - row['A'])
```

but I don't know how to sum such differences in each group and assign the values to a new column say `E`, possibly in a new `df`,

```
C    D          E
M    2017-10    11
M    2017-10    11
B    2017-11    4
B    2017-11    4
A    2018-01    2
```

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example?

Comment: when you `groupby` what function do you want to apply on the difference of columns `A` and `B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on you code

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['C', 'D']).apply(lambda row: row['B'] - row['A']).sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index())
Out[292]: 
           A          B  C        D       0
0 2017-10-01 2017-10-11  M  2017-10 11 days
1 2017-10-02 2017-10-03  M  2017-10 11 days
2 2017-11-01 2017-11-04  B  2017-11  4 days
3 2017-11-08 2017-11-09  B  2017-11  4 days
4 2018-01-01 2018-01-03  A  2018-01  2 days
```

Comment: wondering is it possible to also apply `Timedelta.days` to the one liner code, so i don't have to `df['E'].apply(lambda x: x.days)` later on?

Comment: @daiyue  you can try adding here   df.groupby(['C', 'D']).apply(lambda row:( row['B'] - row['A']).days)

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'`

Comment: @daiyue let us try `df.groupby(['C', 'D']).apply(lambda row: (row['B'] - row['A'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))`

Comment: @daiyue also I think you do not need apply (df.B-df.A).dt.days

Comment: @BEN_YO: In your answer, how can we change the last column's name from `0` to `E`? Could you please add that to your answer?

Comment: @BEN_YO : I got it. `.reset_index(name='E')`