# Find total view time

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I need to get the total view time for a user/episode for the sample data.

```
user_id,episode_name,start_time,end_time
101,Movie1,1,10
101,Movie1,5,15
101,Movie1,18,23
102,Movie1,1,10
102,Movie1,5,15
102,Movie1,18,23
```

Approach was to get the start_time and end_time as a range and then use explode. But its not working.

```
Expected Solution:
user_id,episode_name,total_hours
101,Movie1,19
102,Movie1,19
```

Comment: In what format do you store this data? For example, if you use a Pandas dataframe, you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324988/pandas-sum-the-differences-between-two-columns-in-each-group

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of group-and-islands problem.  I'm going to suggest a cumulative max approach to identify where the islands start.  The idea is to identify the islands and then sum up the values:

```
select user_id, episode_name, min(start_time), max(end_time)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_time >= start_time then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by user_id, episode_name order by start_time) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end_time) over (partition by user_id, episode_name
                                       order by start_time
                                       rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                      ) as prev_end_time
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by user_id, episode_name, grp;
```

To get the total, you can use an additional level of aggregation:

```
with cte as (
      select user_id, episode_name, min(start_time) as start_time, max(end_time) as end_time
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when prev_end_time >= start_time then 0 else 1 end) over
                       (partition by user_id, episode_name order by start_time) as grp
            from (select t.*,
                         max(end_time) over (partition by user_id, episode_name
                                             order by start_time
                                             rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                            ) as prev_end_time
                  from t
                 ) t
           ) t
      group by user_id, episode_name, grp
     )
select user_id, episode_name, sum(end_time - start_time)
from cte
group by user_id, episode_name;
```